# How to pass time_t or simply its date information over COM

Tags: date, visual-c++, com, atl, idl

I have a Visual C++ ATL project which exposes a COM interface.

From my interface, I am calling into FlexNet Publisher libraries. I need to return back a date from these libraries, which expose a `time_t` object I can fetch (yes, I know their libraries are susceptible to the 2038 bug on 32-bit systems).

My IDL file has a method on it which needs to return this date.

Given that I can fetch `time_t`, how do I pass its date information across the COM interface boundary to a client application consuming my COM object? Should I just cast `time_t` as `__int64` and define it as `__int64` in my IDL? What's correct here? What's the standard way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using the oleautomation compliant `DATE` type.

To convert your existing `time_t` type, use the [COleDateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38wh24td.aspx) class, which is provided by ATL. One of its [constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38wh24td.aspx#coledatetime__coledatetime) accepts a `time_t` value and parses it to its equivalent `DATE` value.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to use the `DATE` type or a `VARIANT`. To get there from a `time_t` requires a few conversions.

Headers for the code below:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <oleauto.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <exception>
```

First, get the C++ `time_t` you want to convert.

```
// get the time_t to convert
time_t cpp_time = ...;
```

Then, convert the C++ `time_t` to a Windows `FILETIME`. (This part was lifted from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/167296/how-to-convert-a-unix-time-t-to-a-win32-filetime-or-systemtime)).

```
// convert C++ time_t to Windows FILETIME
FILETIME windows_file_time;
{
    auto ll = Int32x32To64(cpp_time, 10000000) + 116444736000000000;
    windows_file_time.dwLowDateTime = (DWORD)ll;
    windows_file_time.dwHighDateTime = ll >> 32;
}
```

Then, convert the Windows `FILETIME` to a Windows `SYSTEMTIME`.

```
// convert Windows FILETIME to Windows SYSTEMTIME
SYSTEMTIME windows_system_time;
if (!FileTimeToSystemTime(&windows_file_time, &windows_system_time))
    throw new std::exception();
```

Finally, convert the Windows `SYSTEMTIME` to a VARIANT `DATE`.

```
// convert Windows FILETIME to VARIANT DATE
DATE variant_date;
if (SystemTimeToVariantTime(&windows_system_time, &variant_date) != TRUE)
    throw new std::exception();
```

If you want to verify that the above works, you can convert the `DATE` to a string (`BSTR`).

```
// convert DATE to string (for verification purposes)
bstr_t variant_date_string;
if (FAILED(VarBstrFromDate(variant_date, 0, 0, variant_date_string.GetAddress())))
    throw new std::exception();
OutputDebugStringW(variant_date_string);
```

If you need/want to use a `VARIANT` instead of a `DATE`, just wrap the `DATE` in a `VARIANT` struct.

```
// wrap DATE in a VARIANT
VARIANT v_variant_date;
v_variant_date.date = variant_date;
v_variant_date.vt = VT_DATE;
```

To verify that this part works, you can convert that `VARIANT` to a string (`BSTR`).

```
// convert VARIANT to string (for verification purposes)
variant_t v_variant_date_string;
v_variant_date_string.ChangeType(VT_BSTR, &v_variant_date);
OutputDebugStringW(v_variant_date_string.bstrVal);
```